# Nop Commerce - List of users Visiting Store And List of users who have items in their cart

Tags: analytics, nopcommerce

1 ) I am using nop commerce 3.50. I have a requirement where i need to show the list of users visiting my store. I know that there is a feature for showing the details of "online users". How can i get the same details for all users who visits my store. Basically login tracking.

2) I want to get the list of customers who have items added in their cart. how can i get the list of such customers ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can make simple linq query and get all customer list in nop commerce and jsut give conition on customer fields, nop commerce store last login detail in table so you can disply in disanding order so you can get recently login user first...if you want to do this on nop,web side then you need to do some more because i am not sure nop commerce provide customer list on nop.web side, but on admin site it's there.

Comment: regarding cart you need to do same, just find where nop commerce store customer cart details and try to do same make query or get all customer id and then get list....

Comment: @VinitPatel yes. I can certainly do that. I was just confirming if there is any plugin or inbuilt feature that allows this feature.

Comment: No, as per my knowledge there is no such plugin and functnality for that but you can make plugin for this or you can tell to some one who can make it for you....